# I can't access 'My Assets' in the Project Manager Unity

Tags: unity, assets

I was following a tutorial on how to make a 2D Multiplayer Card Game in Unity where they were using the Mirror Networking tool.

I downloaded it from the Assets store, put in my username and password, then it opened the package manager in my Unity editor where I was prompted to sign in again. So I did that in my browser, then it said it was going to redirect me to the Unity Hub. When it redirected me there, nothing happened.

I just want to be able to access the 'My Assets' area - how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I checked back in like 1 hour, now the "My Assets" page doesn't need my sign in? IDK why but I'm glad.

Comment: If you log in when starting Unity from the Unity Hub, you don't need to log in again when Unity is running. The login from the Hub seems to be as well better working than when the login from Hub expired and you try to login within Unity (when Unity is open for a long time). Sometimes the login from within Unity refuses to work at all, in that case a full restart of Hub + Unity usually fixes the problem